# Understanding type inference

Tags: casting, rust, option-type, ownership, inference

I believe I am having a problem with both the data type and ownership of `iter`. It is first declared inside the `for` loop expression. I believe Rust infers that `iter` is of type `u16` because it is being used inside of my computation on line 4.

```rust
  1     let mut numbers: [Option<u16>; 5];                                          
  2     for iter in 0..5 {                                           
  3         let number_to_add: u16 = {  // `iter` moves to inner scope                                            
  4             ((iter * 5) + 2) / (4 * 16)  // Infers `iter: u16`                                 
  5         };                                                                   
  6                                                                                 
  7         numbers[iter] = Some(number_to_add);  // Expects `iter: usize`                 
  8     }
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[std::option::Option<u16>]` cannot be indexed by `u16`
  --> exercises/option/option1.rs:3:9
   |
7  |         numbers[iter] = Some(number_to_add);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
```

- I tried casting `iter` as `u16` inside the computation in line 4, but still having issues.

Where is my misconception?

Comment: *I tried casting `iter` as `u16` inside the computation in line 4, but still receive the same error.* [It isn't the same error.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48fca4fe16313dc19f0d35af338324ce) Add `= [None; 5]` to the declaration of `numbers` and it will compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. And your fix was ok too (it led to a different error, see below).

Your first problem was that for slice indexing, iter needs to be of type `usize` so either

```
numbers[iter as usize] = Some(number_to_add);
```

or

```
((iter as u16 * 5) + 2) / (4 * 16)
```

will lead to correct type inference through rustc.

Your second problem was that numbers was not initialized, so rustc correctly warns you when you try to modify numbers. Assigning a value, e.g.,

```
let mut numbers: [Option<u16>; 5] = [None; 5];
```

will let you compile your program.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the existing answers, a somewhat higher level approach could also be cleaner (depending on taste)

```
let mut numbers = [None; 5];
for (i, n) in numbers.iter_mut().enumerate() {
    let iter = i as u16;
    let number_to_add: u16 = 
        ((iter * 5) + 2) / (4 * 16);

    *n = Some(number_to_add);
}
```

An other alternative would be a more lazy approach, but there's (afaik) no way to e.g. `try_collect` into an array, only `try_from` a slice to an array, so you'd need to collect() to a vec, then `try_from` to an array, which seems less than useful. Though you could always use an iterator to initialise you array:

```
let mut it = (0u16..5).map(|i| ((i * 5) + 2) / (4 * 16));
let numbers = [it.next(), it.next(), it.next(), it.next(), it.next()];
```

Also

> ```
>  // `iter` moves to inner scope
> ```

`iter` is `Copy` so it's just... copied. Kinda. And the block is not useful either, it only contains a simple expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. Just to add, if you only want to initialize your array, you might also consider this way of doing it:

```
let arr_elem = |i: u16| Some(((i * 5) + 2) / (4 * 16));
let numbers : [Option<u16>; 5] = [
    arr_elem(0),
    arr_elem(1),
    arr_elem(2),
    arr_elem(3),
    arr_elem(4),
];
```

This way, you do not need to have it `mut` (at the cost of writing a helper function to initialize a single element and stating the initializer elements, but that could be automated e.g. via a macro or some helper traits).